# If Lestat was able to read minds, how come he didn't see Claudia had in mind to kill him?

Tags: vampire-chronicles, interview-with-the-vampire

Was he not paying attention to the minds of Louis and Claudia? Or was he only able to read human minds, not vampires'?

Answer (score 2):

"Able to read minds" is not the same thing as "constantly does it all the time even to people you don't regard as a threat."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a sire can read the mind of the one he converted.

Comment: From what I remember a sire cant read the mind of first or second generation vamps - that is, vamps he /she sired or his/her children sired - as the generations get further and further away from the sire the minds get more open and the children weaker - also if a child that can be read drinks blood of the sire then they become stronger and their mind also fades and becomes impossible to read